# .htaccess not working Wordpress. Make a url go to a file

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to make a URL go to a file which is a WordPress page template.

I am doing a website that has categories and subcategories then a details page.

First off I am try to make.

```
www.example.com/explore/category_name
```

The `category_name` is dynamic and pulled from a non WordPress database.

I am trying to get that any time the URL is `www.example.com/explore/whatever`. It points to `/wp-content/themes/my_theme/myfile.php`

Here is my `.htaccess` file.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^explore/([a-z0-9-]+)$ /wp-
    content/themes/visitsi_theme/listing-page.php [NC]


    #BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^explore/([a-z0-9-]+)$ /wp-
> content/themes/visitsi_theme/listing-page.php [NC]
> ```

You need to include the `L` flag to prevent the WP directives that follow being processed. I would also remove `NC` flag and make the "whatever" match A-Z if required. Otherwise, `/ExPlOrE/` would be accepted (rather than generating a 404). This directive is also split across two lines (in the middle of the *substitution*) - although maybe that's a typo? (But it certainly needs fixing.)

So, try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^explore/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /wp-content/themes/visitsi_theme/listing-page.php [L]
```

`visitsi` also looks like a typo - but maybe that's intentional?

Providing `/wp-content/themes/visitsi_theme/listing-page.php` is a physical file, then the WP front controller should ignore it.

Comment: The [L] crashes the site?

Throws a 500 error.

Also, visitsi is not a typo.

Comment: Check your error log. The `L` flag itself would not cause this. It's likely to be something in `listing-page.php` that results in an error. (You wouldn't normally expect to be able to rewrite directly to a "WordPress page template"?)

Comment: shouldn't you be able to rewrite to a file though?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to rewrite to a file (that is usually the only thing you do rewrite to). Presumably it "works" if you request `/wp-content/themes/visitsi_theme/listing-page.php` directly?

Comment: Call to undefined function get_header() is what I am getting in the php error log? Any ideas

Comment: If `get_header()` is defined in some other file then it needs to be included. Otherwise, the built-in PHP function is `get_headers()` (with an `s`). That error is likely the cause of the 500 error. But, as mentioned above, if this is a "WordPress page template" then you wouldn't necessarily expect to be able to access it directly - "template" files are usually included/called by other units, not directly. (?)